# jquery multiple version unprdictable error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am working on some very old product which has got multiple version on jquery on it . It is using different third party product which required  specific jquery version .

I have some third party call which gives error

```
jQuery('#'+ObjectName).maxlength({
```

Error ,

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).maxlength is not a function
at setMaximumlengthWithSlider (commonValidators.js:16)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (awardSummary.pfm:17697)
at f (jquery-1.9.0.min.js:1)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.9.0.min.js:1)
at Function.ready (jquery-1.9.0.min.js:1)
at HTMLDocument.xt (jquery-1.9.0.min.js:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your call is wrong, replace this :

```
jQuery('#'+ObjectName).maxlength({
```

With this :

```
$('#'+ObjectName).attr("maxlength")
```

or

```
JQuery('#'+ObjectName).attr("maxlength")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think including this [**library**](http://pioul.fr/ext/jquery-maxlength/jquery.maxlength.min.js) will solve your problem.

*jQuery.maxlength is a lightweight jQuery character counter and countdown for inputs and textareas.*

Here you can find the [**Documentation**](http://pioul.fr/jquery-maxlength)

And this is a code from this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pioul/ysC7L/) :

```
$("#textarea-2").maxlength({
    counterContainer: $(".counter-container")
});
```

Comment: MaxLength third party Plug in is already included in Page,page has got multiple jQuery version which are creating conflict.